# Check if a specific field was updated with a single findOneAndUpdate query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My `items` collection has a following schema:

```json
{
  "item": "box",
  "quantity": 12,
  "lastReportedAt": "2021-10-22T00:12:34"
}
```

Every API call reports the latest quantity for a specific item, so I need to update the doc accordingly.

```js
const newQuantity = 13;
const lastReportedAt = new Date();

db.collection("items").findOneAndUpdate(
  { "item": "box" },
  { $set: { "quantity": newQuantity, "lastReportedAt": newTime } },
  { upsert: true }
);
```

Here I would like to know if there was a change in `"quantity"` field, so that I can be notified.

While some of mongodb's update commands return the number of modified documents, but it also accounts for update in `lastReportedAt` fields.

Is there any way this can be done without using a transaction?

Comment: What do you mean by notified? Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: @MattOestreich No I'm using the native driver. I mean, I just want to check if the "quantity" field of the doc was modified or not (like 12 to 13). To avoid race conditions (multiple requests try to modify the quantity), I would like to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `returnNewDocument` in [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/), and compare with the old document in your application.